# Ubuntu 14.04 cannot connect to my home wifi but shows other available networks

Tags: wireless

I am using ubuntu 14.04 dual booted with windows 7 on my Dell Vostro 2520 . Everything was working fine until ubuntu stopped recognising particularly my home wifi network. I am using a broadcom bcmwl kernel   driver to use wifi. After installing this driver  everything worked fine but one day ubuntu gave me a message " you are now disconnected" . When I opened network settings  it showed my wifi ssid "HOME_WIFI" out of range whereas it recognised other wifi networks nearby my home. It even responded when i opened my phone's wifi hotspot but failed to show my home network . I even restarted my laptop and tried all sorts of commands like killing network processes and all but nothing worked . Finally after changing my wifi router's SSID ubuntu started showing the network again but after some days I expeienced the same problem . I cannot figure out actually what's the problem .
I suppose the drivers are working well as it shows all other available networks except my home network.
All other devices in my home connects to my home wifi without any problem and even there are NO RANGE ISSUES as my laptop is quite near to the wifi modem.
 Please Help !!!

Comment: Which Broadcom? lspci -nn -d 14e4: And which driver? lsmod | grep -e wl -e b43 Welcome to askubuntu!